# Exclude JavaScript from functioning at certain screen size

Tags: javascript

I would like to exclude this JavaScript from functioning at a screen size smaller than 768px.

Do you know what I need to add to the code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var timeOut;
    function scrollToTop() {
        if (document.body.scrollTop!=0 || document.documentElement.scrollTop!=0){
            window.scrollBy(0,-50);
            timeOut=setTimeout('scrollToTop()',10);
        }
        else{ 
            clearTimeout(timeOut);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the size of the screen, current web page and browser window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window)

Comment: Simply attach checking window width in some condition.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your method and you are good to go.

```
if(screen.width > 768) {
   //your method logic
}
```